# SASS to CSS compiler in PhpStorm

Tags: css, sass, phpstorm, auto-compile

I have a periodic problem when PhpStorm automatically compiles SASS into CSS files.
Sometimes it misses some letters in final CSS file.
For example after I write

```
body
    color: #fff
```

I get the following CSS

```
body {
    color: #ff;
}
```

Though the last character is missed. Sometimes it works as it should and compiles everything correctly. Looks like compiler saves changes to css file before SASS changes are completed or vice versa it doesn't catches all my changes in SASS file.
What could be the problem and what is possible solution?

Comment: In your file watcher, is immediate file synchronization turned on? If so, give turning that off a shot as it might be causing your issue.

Comment: I've tried to turn it off, but the issue still remains. It happens not only with 'color' property. Thanks for your reply nonetheless

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. This is caused when phpstorm option to 'always' update is turned on. Whenever phpstorm detects a change it triggers the sass compiler with whatever you have in place. Sometimes it triggers before you finish writing. As far as I know the only solution is to either change to ' update on save '. Or to made a small change like a space and it will retrigger the compiler.

Comment: Thank you for your sharing your experience and explaining possible reasons.